# Как сделать валидацию на вхождение строки в массив Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Хочу сделать валидацию на вхождение строки в массив Laravel.

```
class LangSwitchController extends Controller
{
    $availableLangs = [
        'en',
        'ru',
    ]

    public function switch(Request $request, string $lang)
    {
        

        App::setLocale($lang);

        retutn response()->redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте _in_array($lang, $availableLangs)_

Comment: Ну хоть документацию почитайте: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-in

Comment: Вы $lang из маршрута получаете? Можно как-то так сделать: `Route::get('/{lang}', [LangSwitchController::class, 'switch'])->where('lang', 'ru|en');` [Regular Expression Constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints)